# Flutter receive Intent results from Android app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get videoplayback results from mx_player android intent in flutter, according to their api it possible with intent.

I setup a custom platform which I launch in flutter with:

```
  static const platformMethodChannel = const MethodChannel('mxplayer/native');
  final String result = await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod(url);
```

Then in the android MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.native_code;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "mxplayer/native";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
          if (call.method != null) {
            callapp(call.method);
          }

        });
  }
  public void callapp(String videourl) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
    intent.setClassName("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad", "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.ActivityScreen");
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videourl);
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL");
    intent.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad"); // com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro
    intent.putExtra("return_result", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
  }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)  // -1 RESULT_OK : Playback was completed or stopped by user request.
        //Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: User canceled before starting any playback.
        //RESULT_ERROR (=Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER): Last playback was ended with an error.

        if (data.getAction().equals("com.mxtech.intent.result.VIEW")) {
          //data.getData()

          int pos = data.getIntExtra("position", -1); // Last playback position in milliseconds. This extra will not exist if playback is completed.
          int dur = data.getIntExtra("duration", -1); // Duration of last played video in milliseconds. This extra will not exist if playback is completed.
          String cause = data.getStringExtra("end_by"); //  Indicates reason of activity closure.
        }
    }
}
```

The invoke method works fine and the app is launched and video played, but when video ends I dont receive any status message. I am still learning flutter and I am not familiar with Java so I suspect I am missing something in the MainActiviy.java that handles that "results" callback.

Answer (score 0):

If the video player closes after finishing playback and your app is resumed, AppLifecycleState.resumed in your flutter code

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(state ==  AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      //your code here
    }
  }
```